# Download iOS app without redirecting to App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

Is there a way to allow a user to download & install an iOS app while using another app without redirecting them to the App Store?

The scenario that I'm working on is one where the user is presented with a list of apps that they may choose to download but I do not want them to leave the app.

I tried to search for an iTunes API to do this but I did not find anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[SKStoreProductViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/SKStoreProductViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011852) will allow you to do that. You just set up the itunes ID of the app that you want to download and then you present it as a modal view and the user can take it from there.

You can have a table view with the list of apps that you want the user to download, each with their itunes ID and on selecting one of the items, you can present the view controller.

It looks something like this (iOS 6 screenshot)
[image]

Example use:

```
SKStoreProductViewController *storeViewController = 
              [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];

        storeViewController.delegate = self;

        NSDictionary *parameters =
             @{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier: 
                  [NSNumber numberWithInteger:333700869]};

        [storeViewController loadProductWithParameters:parameters 
             completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
            if (result) {
                [self presentViewController:storeViewController
                                   animated:YES
                                 completion:nil];
            }
        }];
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it silently in the background? I do not want the user to see anything, or at least he needs to see my own UI.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. some certain step needs. First login with Apple develoer ID into iTnues in your PC which you are using in iPhone's `iTnues`, Now browse apps in PC's iTnues there download option will show and download directly from PC , then your app will automatically download to your iPhone in background (it doesn't matter you have app in foreground).

May this help you..

Comment: Answer to a different question.